# filter() and mutate() didn't work when I used the dplyr package on a local PC

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to work with a local PC (offline). I have R 4.3.1 and R Studio 2023.06.1 (Build 524) installed. I downloaded and installed the dplyr 1.1.2. I was able to load `library(dplyr)` and no error messages occurred. The `select()` function worked well. However, when I tried to use the `filter()` and `mutate()` function, this error message occurred:

```
Error in .Call(dplyr_lazy_vec_chop_impl, data, rows, 
private$env_current_group_info, :Incorrect number of arguments (5), 
expecting 2 for 'dplyr_lazy_vec_chop_impl' ".
```

[image: error message]

I had no problem running the same codes on my mac (which is on internet). Does anyone know why this occurred and how I can solve it?

I noticed that when I loaded several dependencies of dplyr (lifecycle 1.0.3, tibble 3.2.0, tidyselect1.2.0, and vctrs 0.6.0, all were in its latest version), warning messages occurred saying that they were built for R 4.4.0. However, the latest R for PC was 4.3.1 (the one I got) at the time of posting this question.

I tried to download earlier versions of those packages but I didn't found any for windows. (The archived versions were for mac only). I got stuck here and was not sure what I should do next.

############ ############ ############ ############ ############
########################  Update Aug 16, 2023 #######################

I would like to thank everyone for spending your precious time helping me diagnose the problem! Following your suggestions, I ran the codes and here are the screenshots of R console. Hope these would help the diagnosis. Looking forward to your suggestions!

This is the first screenshot:
[image: use mtcars data, sessionInfo(), and repo]

This is the second one:
[image: using isS4]

Comment: That's interesting, I have no immediate "sure-fire" thought. Perhaps if an older version of `dplyr` was loaded when you installed 1.1.2, then this might happen (similarly for dependent packages?). I suggest restarting R into a fresh session (no `.Rdata` files, nothing in `ls()`, and `search()` does not list `"package:dplyr"`), _then_ load `library(dplyr)` and try this again.

Comment: If the error persists, sharing your `session_info()` would be helpful too.

Comment: But just to be safe, is `GMData_fs` a "simple" frame? Is `all(sapply(GMData_fs, is.atomic))` true? Is there anything weird about it?

Comment: Also try testing on built-in data that we all know should work, e.g. `filter(mtcars, cyl == 4)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for your suggestion! I tried with mtcars but the same error message occurred. Screenshot is attached to the question. Looking forward to your suggestion!

Comment: @r2evans Yes. "all(sapply(GMData_fs, is.atomic))" This is true. I tried ls(), search(), and then load dplyr, but the problem persists. Please see the screenshot attached to the question. I'd appreciate your thoughts and suggestions!

Comment: The fact that the message from the package load operation said "built for 4.4.0" and that your repo setting was for rstudio means you need to thrash this out with the Posit people. That should NOT be happening. They have there own forum for such matters.

Answer (score 0):

So the workspace did have a function named `filter`. When you get an error about missing argument or incorrect number of arguments, it may mean that:

1. The function has changed and you need to update to the current version, which might mean figuring out which dependent package had the function in the first place. Telling use the output of `sessionInfo()` might help in this instance.
   (In this instance you were warned that the code was built for a different version of R than you think you are using. However, version 1.1.2 was being used as far back as R 4.2.1.)
2. That the code you copied from some website had loaded a different set of packages than you had in place or that a package was loaded after `dplyr` which altered the search path and you have masked the `dpylr::filter` with an identically named function.
3. Or, you (or code you copied) has altered the workspace so that you have replaced the `dplyr::filter` function with one that has a different number of arguments.
4. The object that you passed may have had a special class that has its own version of `filter`. That might be the most likely since your error occurred deep in the bowels of function and argument passing and was the result of a `.Call` invocation of a function named `dplyr_lazy_vec_impl`. What class is the `GMdata_fs` object. Is it S4. If so the filter function might be attached to the class methods.

Try typing:

```
filter   # with a couple of spaces to prevent the annoying habit of Rstudio 
         # automatically adding `()` after a function name when all you wanted was
         #  ..... the damned code.
# Also type:
class(GMdata_fs)
isS4(GMdata_fs)
```

Eventually by looking at the bottom the code at the console output you can figure out what package has the code and whether one of the conditions above is the cause of the confusion.

I'm also wondering how you got packages that were built for version 4.4.0. Show the output for:

```
repo = getOption("repos") 
repo["CRAN"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses! I made edits to the question and added new information. I attached the screenshot of R console when I run sessionInfo(), use filter() with mtcars, and the codes you showed me. Hope this would help diagnose what the problem is.

Comment: To your point #1, I updated all the dependencies of dplyr to the latest version. I think sessionInfo() indicated so (please let me know if I'm wrong). 
To your point #2, I used dplyr::filter to call dplyr but the problem persists. 
To your point #3, I loaded the mtcars data, call dplyr, and used filter() [Please see the screenshot] but the problem persists.